# Creating a new instance for class with a boolean array

Tags: java, boolean, instance

I'm writing a code which changes the colour of an array cell to either black or white depending on what the original colour is. If the cell is white, it changes to black and vice versa. I'm working with the below code:

```
public class Grid {

    boolean[][] grid;
    private int Height;
    private int Width;
    public White;
    public Black;


    public Grid(int height, int width) {

        Height = height;
        Width = width;

    }

    public int getHeight() {

        return Height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {

        return Width;
    }

    public boolean isWhite(int i, int j) {
        boolean [][] Grid = new boolean [Height][Width];
        for ( i = 0; i<Height ; i++);{
            for (j = 0; j<Width ; j++){
                if (Grid[i][j] ?? //iswhite) {
                    ??//setBlack
                }
                else (??)//setWhite

            }
        }

    }}

    protected void setWhite(int i, int j) {
        ??
    }

    protected void setBlack(int i, int j) {
        ??
    }
}
```

I believe I'm supposed to create an instance for Grid[i][j] depending on the boolean value however I'm not sure how to actually relate 'public boolean isWhite' to 'setWhite' and 'setBlack'. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already defined `boolean grid[][]` as a class variable. You'll need to set it up in your constructor with something along the lines of `grid = new boolean[height][width];` I would recommend initializing all the values, just for sanity's sake. (i.e. set them all to true or false or some predefined pattern.)
Once you've done that, you can check `grid[i][j]` for its value, which will either be true or false. (Whichever of those you wish to represent black and white.)

For instance, your isWhite function is as simple as this (assuming white == true)

```
public boolean isWhite(int i, int j) {
        return grid[i][j];
}
```

Similarly, the set functions are also relatively minimal:

```
void setWhite(int i, int j) {
    grid[i][j] = true;
}

void setBlack(int i, int j) {
    grid[i][j] = false;
}
```

Additional:
You would probably want to create some code that does the appropriate thing when flipping colors rather than placing it inside the isWhite function. (It should be testing for color, not changing the values, right?)

```
void changeColorAtYX(int y, int x){
    if(isWhite(y, x)){
        setBlack(y, x);
    } else {
        setWhite(y,x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: Most grids/graphs/etc. are set up in a [x][y] fashion. I noticed you went with y/height first, so I maintained that.

Comment: I actually have another class which is supposed to take care of that (which I'm yet to do. You'll most probably find me back here). Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1) You should probably initialize your array in your constructor.  Since it is an array of primitives it will default to false in every position.  If this is not what you want, set to true as needed.

2) isWhite, judging from the name, should probably just return the value at the given indices.

3) For the set methods, assuming that false == black, just set the value at the appropriate position to true or false depending on whether you want it white or black.